# Is there a way to embed a Sh/Bash session in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, bash, shell

As it [can](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) be done with Python.

I am interested not only in running single shell commands, but also in saving the current environment state.

For example, the following code:

```
system("a=2");
system("echo $a");
```

prints nothing, but I want to find a way by which the program would print "2".

The main goal is to keep the shell environment (that can be initialized, for example, using .bashrc) throughout the entire С/С++ program, as if you work in your terminal.

Comment: A few notes: `system()` only invokes the system shell, and really shouldn't be relied on for anything portable. Only Linux/MacOs, this will likely be bash, on Windows, likely CMD. But still... Also, I'm not really sure why you'd want to use Bash, rather than a more modern scripting language if available. I've seen a lot of embedded scripting languages, but not sure why you'd prefer Bash for extended logic?

Comment: I am confused on what you are looking for.  If you want the environment variables of your process to be "isolated", then it already is: when your C/C++ program runs, a child process is created and you can always change the environment variables without affecting the parent process.

Comment: You would probably need to create and use a bidirectional version of `popen()`, or even a 3-pipe version: one pipe for standard input to the shell, one for standard output from the shell, and one for standard error from the shell.  You'd use functions like `poll()` (`epoll()`) or `select()` to determine whether there's data ready to read from the shell.  You have to worry about all the odd things you can do, running jobs in background, etc.  Determining when the shell is ready for the next input is, in general, very tricky.  Running the shell with the appropriate options is non-trivial, too.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh yeah, I understand all of this. I often have to deal with writing console scripts for Linux and MacOS, and I'm very tired of Bash's limitations. Python does not have the most of its flaws. However, in Python you cannot build pipelines in such a convenient way as in Bash. In order to fix this, I intend to integrate Linux/MacOS shell commands into Python, using a special syntax. And I am not satisfied with existing solutions such as IPython (where Bash doesn't save its environment) and Xonsh (very unsafe).

Comment: Note too that if you want to drive interactive programs like `vim`, you probably need to investigate pseudo-tttys (pseudo-terminals, or ptys).   They have they're own layers of trickery in the setup.  I'm not sure how you'd separate standard output and standard error if using ptys.

Comment: Note that you cannot really do that in Python either (or any other language) if you use system or it's equivalent. setenv or it's analog for language in question (C/Python/Java/etc) is the only way.

Comment: Environment variables aren't the only things to worry about, of course.  Another biggie is the current working directory.  (In other words, `system("cd foo")` is a classic but frustrating no-op.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash does not have an API in the same sense that Python does, but it's a *shell*.  It has a text-based UI that is relatively easy for other programs to use.  You cannot use `system()` because it requires you to specify all shell input up front and blocks until the shell exits, but you can use the same mechanism that `system()` does: run the shell in a separate process.

Details depend on the machine on which your program runs, but on machines where you typically find Bash or another Bourne-family shell -- Linux, Mac, and other POSIX systems -- you have at least two main alternatives:

1. If you want the shell output to go (only) to the host program's standard output and standard error streams, then you can use [`popen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to open a stream connected to a shell:

   ```
   FILE *shell = popen("/bin/bash -i", "w");
   ```

   You could then write an arbitrary sequence of shell commands to the stream, and the shell will receive them on its standard input, execute them, and write the results to its standard output.  The shell launched this way will share the caller's standard output and standard error.
2. If the host program must both feed input to the shell and receive its output then you need to work at a lower level:

   - Use [`pipe()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) to create two pipes (three if you want to capture the shell's standard error separately).
   - [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) a child process in which to run the shell, and in it

     1. [`dup2()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) the appropriate pipe ends onto the child's standard in, out, and (optionally) error.
     2. [`close()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) the pipe ends that the child will not be using
     3. [`execl()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) the shell in the child process.
   - Back in the parent,

     - `close()` the pipe ends the parent will not be using
     - send commands to the shell over the pipe set up for doing so
     - read responses and / or error responses via the pipe(s)
     - when done with the shell `close()` the pipes and [`wait()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) for the child process to terminate.  You can get its exit status at this point if you're interested in that.

Option (2) requires handling a lot more details -- more even than the above overview might suggest.  You will find many answers here on SO that address them if you have need of that.

Comment: Probably the biggest of the "lot more details" is that when you "read responses and / or error responses via the pipe(s)" it's next to impossible to know how much (if any) output there will be.  So you can't use simple, blocking i/o; you'll absolutely need to use some combination of (a) asynchronous i/o, (b) multiple threads, and/or (c) additional "meta i/o" system calls like `select` and `poll`.  (Me, I always prefer (c).)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot accomplish this by calling `system()` because it will be done in new process that will quickly exit.

However, you can call [setenv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) - it will edit environment variables for currently running process (your C program), and it will be inherited by all processes you might create e.g. using `system()`.

Answer (score -4):

Like this:

```c
system("a = 2; echo $a");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I want. The main goal is to keep the shell environment (that can be initialized, for example, using .bashrc) throughout the entire С/С++ program, as if you work in your terminal.